# Two sitebricks services using different HTTP method but with same URL depth, client gets 404

Tags: java, sitebricks

When in the same sitebricks service class

```
 '@At("/r/address/streets")' '@Service'
```

have two services like :

```
'@At("/search") '@Post'

'@At("/:id")' '@Delete'
```

The client gets 404 r/address/streets/search not found
But there should not have problems for separation between both URLs, because two different HTTP methods.

If use

```
'@At("/search") '@Post'

'@At("/delete/:id")' '@Delete'
```

everything works fine

Comment: I know nothing about sitebricks, but giving a 404 on a REST search call should mean that the search found nothing.